# Cannot connect to server client application getting error

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, server, client

Here is my server code:

```
package socketProject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocServer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Server is started");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);

        System.out.println("Server is waiting for the client response");
        Socket s = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Client is connected");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String str = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Client Data:" + str);
    }

}
```

Here is my client code:

```
package socketProject;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocClient {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        String ip="localhost";
        int port =9999;

        Socket s = new Socket(ip,port);

        String str ="Nemi Bhattarai";

        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);
            out.write(str);
            out.flush();


        }


    }
```

Whenever I try to run this I get following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)   at
>   socketProject.SocServer.main(SocServer.java:22)

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting this error, while running the server or client?

Comment: while running the client

Comment: It seems you are not closing the Socket or the streams cleanly in your client.